# Swashbuckle Swagger UI not sending client_secret and client_id to OAuth endpoint when using authentication form

Tags: swagger, auth0, swashbuckle

I have a .NET 5 API project documented with SwaggerGen for which I'm trying to use Swashbuckle as the documentation UI. My auth provider is Auth0, so I'm looking to have the docs generate a JWT bearer token by making a valid OAuth2 call to the Auth0 `/oauth/token` endpoint. The `Authorize` button is appearing on the generated page and produces a form that asks the user for the `client_id` and `client_secret`, but when I press the `Authorize` button it issues a `POST` request that is missing `client_id` and `client_secret`. Specifically, it goes to the correct endpoint (`/oauth/token`) but has no query string parameters and only `grant_type: client_credentials` in the POST body. I can see this in the Chrome developer tools. Somehow the UI is just completely disregarding the values I've typed into the `client_id` and `client_secret` form fields.

Is there a trick to making the auth request use the values from the form? Here is the relevant part of my SwaggerGen configuration:

```cs
options.AddSecurityDefinition("OAuth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
    Name = "Bearer",
    Description = "Authorization using the OAuth2 access token authorization flow",
    Scheme = "Bearer",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows {
        ClientCredentials = new OpenApiOAuthFlow {
            TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://{_configuration["Auth0:HostedDomain"]}/oauth/token"),
            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://{_configuration["Auth0:HostedDomain"]}/authorize")
        }
    }
});

options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "OAuth2"
            }
        },
        new List<string>()
    }
});
```

Comment: did you managed to find a solution for this? I have the same issue...

Comment: Nope. I ended up abandoning Swagger in favour of Stoplight. Stoplight doesn't provide an easy way of authenticating in the test harness, but it looks a lot more professional than Swagger and at least doesn't show a broken authentication form to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the Swagger UI does not send them, i.e. in the authorization header?

I had a similar problem because our OpenID server recognizes only client credentials (`client_id`, `client_secret`) sent in the body form and we have to select the correct `"Client credentials location"` option in the authorization dialog (`Request body`):

---

[image]

Then the `client_id` is sent in the request body correctly:

[image]

Comment: This works for the `password` flow, but there is no "Client credentials location" dialog when using the `application` flow...